# What does the command "rename * *.log *" do?

Tags: linux, rename

I am running Red Hat 7.3.

I typed in `rename * *.log *` with the hope of removing `log` from the names of all files.

I don't this has been happening, and in short, I think somehow files are disappearing.

Comment: Tried this command nothing happens at my end, and what do you mean by files are disappearing? Look at `man rename`

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what program `rename` is on your system (I can't remember for RHEL). If it's the [util-linux rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html), you probably renamed your first file over the second one. Here's what happens. (I'll use `rename.ul` for clarity here.)

With the three files  `a.log`,  `b.log`, and   `c.log` if we give the command `rename.ul * *.log *`, the shell expands the globs and the final command that runs is:

```
rename.ul a.log b.log c.log a.log b.log c.log a.log b.log c.log
```

Now, `rename` takes the first two as a pattern and a replacement, and applies those to the files named by the rest of arguments. So, basically the command tells to replace `a.log` with `b.log` in the names of any of `c.log a.log b.log c.log a.log b.log c.log`. Only `a.log` matches, and it's moved over `b.log`, and you probably get an error message for the *next* `a.log` listed.

If your `rename` was the [Perl rename](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/perl/prename.1.en.html) (`prename`) instead, you would probably have gotten an error without anything happening, since your first filename is likely to not be a valid Perl command. `prename` also doesn't overwrite files by default.

---

With the util-linux rename, to remove `.log` from the file names, you'd use

```
$ rename.ul .log "" *.log
```

That would change any matches from the middle of the name too, so `v.logger` would turn into `vger`.

With the Perl rename, the command would be

```
$ prename 's/\.log$//' *.log
```

Comment: The second is what I observed in my test case on Ubuntu, but again OP says files are disappearing. I wonder what OP means by that!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, well, try with the util-linux `rename`. You might have it as `rename.ul`. They're different tools, Debian/Ubuntu have the Perl tool as default, but I can't find a source on what other Linuxen have behind the name `rename`.